# Two mounts of same file from same image: error on unmouting first image

Tags: mount

I want to be able to mount two (and possibly more) sets of image and file (squashfs) from the image and unmount them independently. However, when both sets had been mounted (1st then 2nd), `umount` 1st image mount point fails with `target is busy` (after `umount` 1st mount point of file succeeds). Code below.

When all mounted initially, `findmnt` shows both sets of mounts of image and file "occupy" same loop devices (one for image and one for file). To counter that, I've tried to mount image to different loop device with `mount -o loop=/dev/loopx`, but it resulted in `overlaping loop device exists`. Any there any ways to avoid copying image and still mount/unmount image + file independently?

BTW mounting file 2nd time outputs extra (compared to 1st): `WARNING. source write-protected`.

P.S. web search found [How to mount multiple partitions from disk image simultaneously?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342463/how-to-mount-multiple-partitions-from-disk-image-simultaneously) and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1836914 which IMO are related but not directly.

Code:

```
mkdir i_1 i_2 s_1 s_2
mount img i_1
WARNING: source write-protected, mounting read-only.
mount img i_2
WARNING: source write-protected, mounting read-only.
mount i_1/filesystem.squashfs s_1
mount i_2/filesystem.squashfs s_2
WARNING: source write-protected, mounting read-only.
umount s_1
umount i_1
target is busy.
```

For reperformance one may take some distro iso as image file (substituting proper path to squashfs file).

Comment: You write « findmnt shows ... », « mounting file 2nd time outputs  ... », etc. but we don't know what command you actually executed. Please copy-paste into your question the exact commands and their output. My understanding is that you are mounting files found inside another squashfs file, which would explain the perfectly legit message "target is busy". Why do you want to unmount the squashfs image if it is in use?

Comment: @xhienne, I thought it was clear but "mounting files found inside another squashfs file" showed you got me wrong. I've added code. Please see again.